# Symfony 3.3.5 config service

Tags: symfony

I have some class ObjectManager and want create service for him, I create config

```
services:
_defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    public: false

AppBundle\:
    resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
    exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository,Tests}'

AppBundle\Service\:
    resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Service'
    public: true

app.object_manager:
    class: AppBundle\Service\ObjectManager
    arguments:
        - '@jms_serializer'
        - '@validator'
```

and after get this service in controller and have error

```
$objectManager = $this->get('app.object_manager');

You have requested a non-existent service "app.object_manager".
```

Why this happened, symfony 3.3.5 have different way for config services ?

Comment: public: false is now the default which mean the services cannot be accessed via Container::get().  Add public: true to your service definition.  Better yet, take a look at how to inject your service directly into an action method.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when you want to be able to call a service with get, you have to define it public.

```
app.object_manager:
    class: AppBundle\Service\ObjectManager
    public: true
```

But you can do that also in top of the services.yml, to define, that all services are public:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: true
```

That way, you don't have to do it explicitly at every service.

Furthermore, I would recommend you, to use the new autowiring feature of Symfony. That way, you do not have to define a service in the services.yml.

Just define the constructor in your ObjectManager class like that:

```
class ObjectManager
{
    private $jms_serializer;
    private $validator;

    public function __construct(SerializerInterface $jms_serializer, ValidatorInterface $validator)
    {
        $this->jms_serializer   = $jms_serializer;
        $this->validator        = $validator;
    }
}
```

He will find the correct services by autowiring then. And you do not have to define anything in the services.yml.

So, to sum up your services.yml should just contain the following:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: true

AppBundle\:
    resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
    exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository,Tests}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to explicitly define your services as public since Symfony 3 if you want to use them through get().

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        # ...
        public: false
```

More info here - http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#public-versus-private-services

Answer (score 0):

You can actually **use Symfony 3.3+** to it's [full potential](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/05/07/how-to-refactor-to-new-dependency-injection-features-in-symfony-3-3/).

If I understand you correctly, you need to get `AppBundle\Service\ObjectManager` to your Controller.

In that case...

#### 1. Modify your `services.yml`

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true

    AppBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
        exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository,Tests}'
```

#### 2. Require `AppBundle\Service\ObjectManager` via constructor (anywhere you need it)

```
use AppBundle\Service\ObjectManager;

final class MyController
{
    /**
     * @var ObjectManager
     */
    private $objectManager;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    public function someAction()        
    {
        $this->objectManager->someCoolMethod();
    }
}
```

That's all!

Nothing fancy, just pure Symfony awesomes!